How to add in jsonLogic a variable with jsonLogic rule
I would like to use a varible inside a jsonLogic rule
rule = {"+": [{"var": "a"}, 2]} 
    
data = {"a": {"*": [3,4]}}

result = jsonLogic.apply(rule, date)

that's return null and I want 14 as result.
Any idea?
